# Symfony Sonata Admin Embedded template

Tags: mongodb, symfony, templates, sonata-admin

**Situation**

I've got a site where users can have required learning to them in the a 1:M format. The admin area for required learning is embedded in the users profile.
I would however like to change the template used on this specific admin page.

[image: Embedded admin]

**Problem**

I am familliar with using different template sets however the sub admin appears to be using a completely different display set from the normal admin set as depicted in the screenshot below, courtesy of the Symfony profiler

[image: Twig Profiler]

I've checked out the [Sonata admin templates](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/templates.html#configuring-templates) and can't think which template I should actually be using in the override.

**Question**

- Please can you offer some guidance on what steps I should be taking in order to override this template properly?
- Is the template override set in the parent admin or the embedded admins config?

Thank you for taking the time to read this question :)

Comment: After more sifting, I've just come across http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19873566/custom-template-in-sonata-admin. Just testing it now

Comment: No luck with the above...It just seems ignored